# Commit files went to previous commit

Tags: git

I made 2 commits B and C and then I did

```
git reset soft HEAD~2
```

then I did some some changes and added the modified files back with git add and then I did git commit but these changes went onto the previous commit A.
Why is this happening and how can I fix this.

Comment: What do you want to do? The reason why the --soft parameter works as you described is written in the git documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**git reset soft** will just point HEAD to previous commit but didn't change index location. index will still point to latest commit.

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
```

You should use **git reset hard** this will move HEAD & index both to previous commit.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```